# How can I get the Django SplitDateTimeWidget to recognize AM/PM inputs?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-forms, django-widget

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the `SplitDateTimeWidget` ([link to ref doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeWidget)) to recognize AM/PM inputs.

I've tried both the template-style input:

```
widgets={'start_datetime':forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(time_format='h:i A')}
```

and the standard Python time inputs ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913700/django-forms-timefield-validation)):

```
widgets={'start_datetime':forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(time_format='%I:%M %p')}
```

As you could guess, `start_datetime` is a `DateTimeField` in my model:

```
start_datetime=models.DateTimeField('Start', default=datetime.now())
```

Nothing I do seems to get this to pass validation -- I keep getting errors in that field. Any suggestions? I've been searching now for 2 hours to no avail. I can get it to validate if I stick with 24-hour time or if I leave out the AM/PM part, but I'd rather be able to correctly interpret AM/PM.

Thanks

Comment: After a lot of researching, I realized time_format isn't what I want at all. time_format only specifies how the default form value will look -- NOT how the input data is parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, after poking around a lot in the source for the `SplitDateTimeWidget`, I didn't see a way to pass `input_time_formats` into the widget. Perhaps there is a way (I don't understand the common lineage between fields and widgets well enough to say for sure one way or another), but I couldn't find it.

However, I was able to get it working by overriding the fields and using `SplitDateTimeField` in the ModelForm (original fields in model are `DateTime` type). I then needed to pass the `DateTime` from the `SplitDateTimeField` back to the original model, since the form field and the model field were unlinked since I overrode it.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  start_datetime=forms.SplitDateTimeField(input_time_formats=['%I:%M %p'])
  end_datetime=forms.SplitDateTimeField(input_time_formats=['%I:%M %p'])

  class Meta:
    model=MyModel
    exclude=('start_datetime','end_datetime')

  def clean(self):
    self.instance.start_datetime=self.cleaned_data.get('start_datetime')
    self.instance.end_datetime=self.cleaned_data.get('end_datetime')
```

Comment: does it mean that without the changes you've made the code here does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just override `django.contrib.admin.widgets.AdminSplitDateTime`

This is the code:

```
class CustomAdminSplitDateTime(AdminSplitDateTime):
def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    widgets = [AdminDateWidget, AdminTimeWidget(attrs=None, format='%I:%M %p')]
    forms.MultiWidget.__init__(self, widgets, attrs)
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model=MyModel
    exclude=()
    start_datetime= forms.DateField(
        widget=CustomAdminSplitDateTime()
    )
    end_datetime= forms.DateField(
        widget=CustomAdminSplitDateTime()
    )
```

Don't forget to add the time format to the supported formats in your settings file, e.g.:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%I:%M %p',
    '%H:%M:%S',
    '%H:%M:%S.%f',
    '%H:%M'
]
```